# Why does RecyclerView onClick method doesn't work?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Actually i've made that when i press on some items from recyclerView they get highlited by changing their background.

But the issue come's when i try to use adapter.onClick method in the activity i mean if i don't use the method in adapter where i change color the onClick in activity works but when i use it in adapter that doesn't.

in activity i was just trying to make a Toast for making a test by clicking on an item from recyclerView but that doesn't work if i have the method where i change the items color background on selected.

Here is my adapter code:

```
public class AdapterVarianti extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterVarianti.ExampleViewHolder>  implements Filterable {


    private ArrayList<VariantiConstructor> variantiConstructors;
    private ArrayList<VariantiConstructor> mFilteredList;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public interface  OnItemClickListener{
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public AdapterVarianti.ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.varianti_recycler,parent,false);
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        v.setLayoutParams(lp);
        return new AdapterVarianti.ExampleViewHolder(v, mListener);
    }

    AdapterVarianti(ArrayList<VariantiConstructor> exampleList){
        variantiConstructors = exampleList;
        mFilteredList = variantiConstructors;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final AdapterVarianti.ExampleViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final VariantiConstructor item = mFilteredList.get(position);

        holder.desc.setText(item.getDeskT());
        holder.prepiu.setText(String.valueOf(item.getPrice()));
        holder.premeno.setText(String.valueOf(item.getPacq()));

        if(position % 2 == 0 ){
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#17e1a0"));

        }else if(position % 2 == 1){
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#7EC0EE"));
        }

//CHANGING COLOR ON CLICK AND BACK TO MAIN COLOR IF CLICKED AGAIN!

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                item.setSelected(!item.isSelected());
                if(position % 2 == 0 ) {
                    holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(item.isSelected() ?  Color.parseColor("#f4c542") : Color.parseColor("#17e1a0"));
                }else if(position % 2 == 1){
                    holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(item.isSelected() ?  Color.parseColor("#f4c542") : Color.parseColor("#7EC0EE"));
                }
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {

        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {

                String charString = charSequence.toString();

                if (charString.isEmpty()) {

                    mFilteredList = variantiConstructors;
                } else {

                    ArrayList<VariantiConstructor> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (VariantiConstructor androidVersion : variantiConstructors) {

                        if (androidVersion.getDeskT().toLowerCase().contains(charString)) {

                            filteredList.add(androidVersion);
                        }
                    }

                    mFilteredList = filteredList;
                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = mFilteredList;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                mFilteredList = (ArrayList<VariantiConstructor>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mFilteredList.size();
    }

    public class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView desc;
        public TextView prepiu;
        public TextView premeno;

        ExampleViewHolder(View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
            super(itemView);

            desc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Desc);
            prepiu = itemView.findViewById(R.id.PrePiu);
            premeno = itemView.findViewById(R.id.PreMeno);


            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(listener != null){
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                            listener.onItemClick(position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });


        }
    }

    public void removeItem(int position) {
        variantiConstructors.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

}
```

While here is the code from my Activity when i try to make a Toast:

```
adapterVarianti.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterVarianti.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {
        if(tipo.toString().equals("CON ") || tipo.toString().equals("PIU' ") || tipo.toString().equals("MENO ") || tipo.toString().equals("SENZA ")) {
            tipo.append(filteredVariable.get(position).getDeskT());
            Toast.makeText(pterm.this,tipo,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            tipo = new StringBuilder();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You are setting `OnClickListener`  2 times. One in `onBindViewHolder` method and other in ViewHolder calss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does RecyclerView onClick method doesn't work?

mainly, in your case, it is because you are overriding it in `onBindViewHolder` with:

`holder.itemView.setOnClickListener`

being a setter the last wins. The easy solution in your case is to call `onItemClick` from there.

Comment: so you suggest to use onClick only onBindView instead of ViewHolder?

Comment: you can use one. Pick and move your logic accordingly

Comment: Yeah i've got that i can use just one but still the question is is better to use it onBind or on ViewHolder?

Comment: in terms of performance it doesn't make difference. I would move the logic in the holder and keep the `onBindViewHolder` smaller.

Answer (score 1):

Because you set onclick listener for your itemView twice, in  `onBindViewHolder` and `ExampleViewHolder`
so please remove below code in `onBindViewHolder`

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                item.setSelected(!item.isSelected());
                if(position % 2 == 0 ) {
                    holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(item.isSelected() ?  Color.parseColor("#f4c542") : Color.parseColor("#17e1a0"));
                }else if(position % 2 == 1){
                    holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(item.isSelected() ?  Color.parseColor("#f4c542") : Color.parseColor("#7EC0EE"));
                }
            }
        });
```

and update your `ExampleViewHolder` constructor

```
 itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                final VariantiConstructor item = mFilteredList.get(position);
                item.setSelected(!item.isSelected());
                if(position % 2 == 0 ) {
                    itemView.setBackgroundColor(item.isSelected() ?  Color.parseColor("#f4c542") : Color.parseColor("#17e1a0"));
                }else if(position % 2 == 1){
                    itemView.setBackgroundColor(item.isSelected() ?  Color.parseColor("#f4c542") : Color.parseColor("#7EC0EE"));
                }
                if(listener != null){
                    if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                        listener.onItemClick(position);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you are set the onClickListener in your `ViewHolder` and in your `onBindViewHolder`. Just comment this lines:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            item.setSelected(!item.isSelected());
            if(position % 2 == 0 ) {
                holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(item.isSelected() ?  Color.parseColor("#f4c542") : Color.parseColor("#17e1a0"));
            }else if(position % 2 == 1){
                holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(item.isSelected() ?  Color.parseColor("#f4c542") : Color.parseColor("#7EC0EE"));
            }
        }
    });
```

It should works now